# MySQL query optimization to get 8-10 records from a large table

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

We have a small mobile app, that keep sending the teams locations working in the field. We have web-based admin panel to see the last location of each team in the field, there are 8-10 teams.

Now, the table that save the locations, becoming bigger (around 800K records) and it is taking about 10 seconds to get the info from the db.

We can not simply remove the old records, as we want to keep the history of the teams visits on different location.

In the view, We are using the following SQL query in our admin panel

```
SELECT w.ID, w.DaynTime, team_Desc, co_Nome, w.team_Lat, w.team_Long
FROM ( SELECT MAX(ID) AS maxID FROM VlocationTab GROUP BY UserID) AS aux
INNER JOIN VlocationTab AS w ON w.ID = aux.maxID;
```

Here is the create statement

```
CREATE TABLE `TableName` (
 `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `UserID` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
 `Lat` double(8,6) NOT NULL,
 `Long` double(8,6) NOT NULL,
 `DayTime` datetime NOT NULL,
 `User` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
 `Date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`AUser` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
`ADate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
KEY `DataTime` (`DayTime`),
KEY `Coordenates` (`Lat`,`Long`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1040384 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Is there anyway to optimize this query to minimize the execution time please ?

Comment: Do you have any indexes ? Did you try running `EXPLAIN` on your MySQL query ? Not sure why this question is tagged with PHP.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query
. In addition, as per the comment above, questions about query performance always require CREATE TABLE statements for all relevant tables as well as the EXPLAIN.

Comment: @Maximus2012 we have three indexes, one on primary key, other on date and time and 3rd on Lat and Long. Tried Explain but do not understand much.

Comment: (That said, I suspect that there's not much room for optimization here) :-(

Comment: Astute partitioning can aid query performance, but it has to be done just right. Unfortunately, it's beyond my pay grade to say how.

Comment: @Strawberry with that kind of comments , your pay grade will be the same :-(

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: Where do `co_name` and `team_Desc` come from ?????  If you have "simplified" the query for the question, you may have left out important clues !!!

Comment: How big is the table (GB)?  How much RAM do you have?  What is the value of `key_buffer_size`?

Comment: You should plan to migrate to InnoDB from MyISAM.

Comment: @RickJames The query is optimize with a little bit tweaking, will post it later. Mysql version is 5.5.51-Maria DB, on QS-Pro-III server. Ram 8GB with 512MB flash memory. The query is same, but we are using a view, that get co_Name and team_desc from team table. thank you for your help.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE VIEW`; the details there could make a _huge_ difference in optimization !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I populate a test table with 1000000 lines (1000 users and 1000 lines per user)

Here is the initial plan :

```
mysql> explain SELECT w.ID, w.DayTime, User, Lat, `Long` FROM ( SELECT MAX(ID) AS maxID FROM TableName GROUP BY UserID) AS aux INNER JOIN TableName AS w ON w.ID = aux.maxID;
+----+-------------+------------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------+---------+----------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | partitions | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref       | rows    | filtered | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------+---------+----------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | NULL       | ALL    | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL      | 1000000 |   100.00 | Using where                     |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | w          | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | aux.maxID |       1 |   100.00 | NULL                            |
|  2 | DERIVED     | TableName  | NULL       | ALL    | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL      | 1000000 |   100.00 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------+---------+----------+---------------------------------+
3 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT count(*) FROM ( SELECT MAX(ID) AS maxID FROM TableName GROUP BY UserID) AS aux INNER JOIN TableName AS w ON w.ID = aux.maxID;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|     1000 |
+----------+
1 row in set (1.07 sec)
```

Your subquery

> SELECT MAX(ID) AS maxID FROM TableName GROUP BY UserID
>   cannot use any index, so you do a full scan to search max(id) per user, next join with the primary key.

I add an index with two columns, user and id. As the index is ordonned it allow to directly get the max(id) per user :

```
mysql> alter table TableName add index UserID_ID(UserID,ID);
Query OK, 1000000 rows affected (10.60 sec)
Records: 1000000  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

new plan and time :

```
mysql> explain SELECT w.ID, w.DayTime, User, Lat, `Long` FROM ( SELECT MAX(ID) AS maxID FROM TableName GROUP BY UserID) AS aux INNER JOIN TableName AS w ON w.ID = aux.maxID;
+----+-------------+------------+------------+--------+---------------+-----------+---------+-----------+------+----------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | partitions | type   | possible_keys | key       | key_len | ref       | rows | filtered | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+--------+---------------+-----------+---------+-----------+------+----------+--------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | NULL       | ALL    | NULL          | NULL      | NULL    | NULL      | 1001 |   100.00 | Using where              |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | w          | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY   | 4       | aux.maxID |    1 |   100.00 | NULL                     |
|  2 | DERIVED     | TableName  | NULL       | range  | UserID_ID     | UserID_ID | 47      | NULL      | 1001 |   100.00 | Using index for group-by |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+--------+---------------+-----------+---------+-----------+------+----------+--------------------------+
3 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT count(*) FROM ( SELECT MAX(ID) AS maxID FROM TableName GROUP BY UserID) AS aux INNER JOIN TableName AS w ON w.ID = aux.maxID;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|     1000 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.04 sec)
```

PS : But the best way is to rewrite your request to filter on date first, for example lines younger than one day.

Comment: thank you for your efforts, I added a new index on UserID and ID. it did not help. Then I add a filter, (where clause), as you suggest, to show only the lines/recds of last 2 days, it reduce execution time to 8s. anything else we can do?

Comment: @qammarferoz - Please show us the `EXPLAIN` after adding that index.